# string to map conversion in Groovy

Tags: groovy

I have a string like `def data = "1,2,3,4,5"`
I want to convert it to a map with empty value string

```
buildList =  ['1':,
             '2':,
             '3':,
             '4':,
             '5':,
]
```

I'm just starting groovy learning and need you help

Comment: What is an "empty value string" - assuming you mean an empty string, then your example code lacks the string for the value.  Or do you mean `null`? Anyway: what have you tried ahd how has it failed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will first need to split the string into the keys, and then insert each key into a map. I assume you want an empty string as the value in each case:

```
def data = "1,2,3,4,5"
def map = [:]
data.split(",").each{ item ->
        map.put(item, "")
}
println map
```

Comment: This works, thank you. Can I add buildList to map? like
buildList = [
   '2': ,
   '3': ,
   '4': ,
   '5': ,
]

Comment: If you want a list with just the keys, use only the _data.split(",")_ part

Comment: No, I mean the structure should be 
```buildList = [
    '1': ,
    '2': ,
    '3': ,
    '4': ,
    '5': ,
 ]
```
But this is still a map. So next time I can call it 
```map.buildList.each {
   some actions
 }
```

Comment: That's not how maps work. You want a list of keys that you can then do stuff with. Or insert dummy values (like empty strings) into the map for each key. You **cannot** have a map with keys only.

Comment: Rather than each and a mutation, I prefer this style `def map = data.split(",").collectEntries { item -> [item, ''] }`

Answer (score 1):

one-liner version:

```
def data = "1,2,3,4,5"

def map = data.split( ',' ).collectEntries{ [ it, '' ] }

assert map.toString() == '[1:, 2:, 3:, 4:, 5:]'
```